# extract a web page to excel

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I found many ajax plug-in to add button for extracting web page or table to excel but the web page I want to extract is not mine so I don't have an access to add the plugin.

the process will be started by just running an exe file that I will be doing and the application will access the URL of the web page and then save the extracted excel file..
so the exe will be running from time to time to execute the process without the help of anyone.

I don't have any idea on what should I research so I'm asking for your suggestion for the technology that I should use.

My supervisor asked me to do the exe on C#

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can code in C# you can use the HTML agility pack to extract almost anything from a webpage you can then convert that to a datatable of sorts in c# and populate an excel spreadsheet quite easily there are plenty of examples on the agility pack see this thread [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Comment: also see this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74b3cfd7-7d6f-4583-8e4b-72ae59ea6d22/parsing-html-data-from-a-webpage-in-c-to-an-excel-file?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Sounds good that HTML Agility Pack can extract HTML pages.. does it has an export to excel functionality or it will be another process to export the extracted data to excel?

Comment: you need to separate it into steps 1 extract data, 2 convert or do something with the data and then 3 save, and  in your case excel (perhaps csv), so you need to look at the challenge a step at a time, if you can do step 1 then onwards and upwards give it a go! And post your code if you fail, you'll get there in the end

Comment: Jomer, you should accept the answer if you agree it